# Any recommendation to manage an investigation projects?

Tags: methodology, development-methodologies, extreme-programming

I'm working on an investigation on the [NLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Processing) field. Since software engineering and software documentation are not the primary concerns of my whole investigation I decided to do it using [XP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_Programming).

My question is, can you recomend:

- Any tool you've used to manage XP projects
- Any recomendation/link on how to manage investigation projects

I'm very biased with XP because I've used it before, but if anyone has a better methodology you can post it as well

Comment: " Since software engineering and software documentation are not the primary concerns of my whole investigation I decided to do it using XP" What on earth makes you think XP doesn't care about those things?

Comment: @Rein, sure I know that XP does care about documentation and software engineering, but what I meant is that is more suitable to my purpouses than say, RUP which is really heavy, don't know if I explain myself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XPlanner](http://www.xplanner.org/) is my favorite XP/Scrum planning and management tool. It isn't heavy on reporting, but it gives me what I need. I've also used [Rally](http://www.rallydev.com/), which is more suited to large organizations and is a bit heavy for the daily team tasks. If you need detailed reports for upper management, it does a good job.

As for how to manage investigation, I have my teams set definable goals. Tasks have definable success/failure/completion states and aren't vague. So we end up with tons of short tasks like "Test REST interface for performance capabilities" and "Examine proxy/firewall restrictions for client" rather than "Explore REST". New tasks go up all the time and forces us to have very short sprints. In the range of 3-5 days. You just can't plan exploration out much further than that in the beginning because you don't know what you don't know.

Comment: Can you recommend me a specific version? I downloaded a beta of XPlanner 0.7, but it's painful to install .. thx

Comment: @David Sorry, I didn't do the install and configuration (had my IT guys do that).